# $\liminf 1_G(Y_n)\geq 1_G(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading a proof, but I stuck in this part of that proof:

$Y_n\to Y$ a.s., since $G$ is a open set, $\liminf 1_G(Y_n)\geq 1_G(Y)$.

Why is this true? Thanks.

Comment: @DionelJaime yes. But why Fatou’s Lemma is important in $G$ being open set?

Comment: You can use Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Here Fatou's lemma is not relevant at all. The fact is that, for any open set $G$, $1_G$ always has the property that, if $x_n\to x$ ($x_n$ deterministic sequence, not  random variables), then $\liminf 1_G(x_n)\geq 1_G(x)$

Comment: My bad . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ is open, [$1_G$ is lower semicontinuous](https://books.google.fr/books?id=B7Ch-c2G21MC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=indicator+function+of+open+set&source=bl&ots=To3AoTD9V-&sig=xZv4dGY4XyBJzufgPH0jwiCcZUw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjes9iYkJTZAhUFUlAKHR1QBJAQ6AEIRjAC#v=onepage&q=indicator%20function%20of%20open%20set&f=false).  As $Y_n \to Y$ a.s., $\liminf_n Y_n \ge Y$ a.s.  Passing it into the lower semicontinuous function $1_G$ gives $\liminf_n 1_G(Y_n)\geq 1_G(Y)$.